# Error in eval(inp, data, env) : object 'database' not found

Tags: r

I wrote the following function in  R

```
Plots <- function (database, variable) {
   fit <- survfit(Surv(database$Months) ~ variable, data = database)
   ggsurvplot(fit, data = database, pval = TRUE)
   surv_pvalue(fit, data = database)
}
```

When I call it like so Plots(DB,DB$variable) I get the following error:

```
 Error in eval(inp, data, env) : object 'database' not found
```

At first I thought there was a problem with passing the variable but when I only kept the first line like so:

```
Plots <- function (database, variable) {
    fit <- survfit(Surv(database$Months) ~ variable, data = database)
}
```

It worked fine.
and when I just replaced it with print(database) it also worked.
Thus I am thinking the object is somehow being removed after it's first use or something weird like that.

Has anyone encountered this? 
Any ideas would be great :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the problem comes from ggsurvplot. Quickly checking I think there is a similar problem reported in [github](https://github.com/kassambara/survminer/issues/283). 
ggsurvplot tries to use this formula `Surv(database$Months) ~ variable` on your the data you provide, but in the function `ggsurvplot()`, your data is not called database.. Ok I hope it's not too confusing.

A work-around is to define your independent (yvar) and dependent (xvar) variable as strings, and feed the formula to feed:

```
Plots <- function (database, yvar,xvar) {
   FORMULA = as.formula(paste("Surv(",yvar,") ~ ",xvar))
   fit <- survfit(FORMULA, data = database)
fit$call$formula = FORMULA
list(
   plot= ggsurvplot(fit, data=database,pval = TRUE),
   p = surv_pvalue(fit, data = database)
)
}

Plots(lung,"time","ph.ecog")

$plot

$p
  variable        pval   method   pval.txt
1  ph.ecog 0.004561623 Log-rank p = 0.0046
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure why but when I try to run it, even with the sample db "lung" i get:  Error in eval(FORMULA) : object 'FORMULA' not found

Comment: Hi @EdiItelman sorry I thought I fixed the issue with the formula. Thanks for checking it.Use the fix above, it should work for you